# Maximum number of rotations to recover height balanced property in an AVL tree

Tags: rotation, computer-science, avl-tree

If a new node is inserted at depth d into an AVL tree, what is the maximum number of rotations that may be required to recover the height balanced property?

I had guessed it may be log2(d) for the maximum, but that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you adopt the naive approach, you can normalize and round up the fundamental AVL balance

{left,even,right} ~ {down,even,up} ~ {green,green,red}

and clear the route all green before the insertion.

Each red-light requires at most 2 rotations, which does not include the subtree cost. The problem is that within the 4 quad-subtrees rotated, there is 1 subtree height that remains invariant.

If the next light is the green light, you need only 2 rotations for each red-light (which excludes the subtree rotation cost.)

In order to move down a new green-light from the tree-top, you have to rotate the red-lights one by one from the tree-top.

Answer (score -2):

On insertion, only at most 1 rotation is needed. You can read about it at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

On deletion, it is possible that a rotation is needed on every level of the tree, so deletion is O(log2(d))

Comment: Question asks about the maximum number of rotations to recover
so its quoted there in the wiki `The time required is O(log n) for lookup, plus a maximum of O(log n) retracing levels (O(1) on average) on the way back to the root, so the operation can be completed in O(log n) time`

Comment: Left right case and right left case both require two rotations to recover.